# Deleting elements of a List (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I just started to learn **Haskell**.

I have a list of words and have to

1. delete the first letters of all words then
2. delete all words that start with the letter "a", and
3. put the remaining words together.

i managed to do  1 and 3 but cant figure out how to delete the words that start with an "a"

so far it looks like:

```
concat(--remove words with a--(map (drop 1) ["Tree","House","Monkey","Haskell","Informatik"]))
```

Thank you Frerich Raabe, it works

Comment: `filter` and `!!` might be useful.

Comment: Instead if `!!`, you might prefer `head`. Don't forget - a string is just a list of characters.

Comment: could you be more specific?
How do I filter out the words with a?

Comment: It's difficult to be more specific without doing your homework for you.

Comment: Right, `head` is better as we only need the first character.

Comment: `!!` and `head` are both bad advice in this context. Single letter words become `""` after step 1, then `!!`/`head` would provoke an error.

Comment: `take 1` could replace head for example. Anyway this question look pretty similar than this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390173/haskell-filter-string-list-based-on-some-conditions/16390238)

Answer (score 7):

It's better to think of it the other way. You want to filter the list so that you keep the words that don't begin with `'a'`. You can do this using the standard function [`filter`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3afilter).

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The first argument to `filter` is a function which should return `True` for the words that you want to keep, and `False` for the ones you want to delete, and the second argument is your list.

```
filter doesNotBeginWithA (... your list goes here ...)
```

Now you have to implement this function. You can do this using simple pattern matching.

```
doesNotBeginWithA :: String -> Bool
doesNotBeginWithA xs = ...
```

---

If you're familiar with function composition, using `not` to invert your logic is slightly more idiomatic. You could also generalize it a little:

```
filter (not . beginsWith 'a') (...)
```

Now you have to provide this function instead:

```
beginsWith :: Char -> String -> Bool
beginsWith c xs = ...
```