# Removing a string from a list of strings in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I have a question regarding Haskell that's been stumping my brain. I'm currently required to write a function that removes a string i.e. `"word"` from a list of strings `["hi", "today", "word", "Word", "WORD"]` returns the list `["hi", "today", "Word", "WORD"]`. I cannot use any higher-order functions and can only resort to primitive recursion.

Thinking about the problem, I thought maybe I could solve it by using a recursion where you search the head of the first string, if it matches `"w"` then compare the next head from the tail, and see if that matches `"o"`. But then I soon realized that after all that work, you wouldn't be able to delete the complete string `"word"`.

My question really being how do I compare a whole string in a list rather than only comparing 1 element at a time with something like: `removeWord (x:xs)`. Is it even possible? Do I have to write a helper function to aid in the solution?

Comment: The fact that your list contains strings isn't really important here. Try solving the problem for e.g. list of `Int` first, then it should be just a matter of changing the type signature to make it work for lists of strings.

Comment: When you match `(x:xs)` against `["hi", "today", "word", "Word", "WORD"]`, `x` becomes `"hi"` and `xs` becomes `["today", "word", "Word", "WORD"]`. That is, it matches string by string, not character by character. This works because you have a *list* of strings rather than just one big string.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much this is where it was giving me trouble. I thought it was only the first element and not the whole word. This clears up everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the base case: removing a word from an empty list will be the empty list. This can be trivially written like so:

```
removeWord [] _ = []
```

Now consider the case where the list is not empty. You [match](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching) this with `x:xs`. You can use [a guard](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) to select between these two conditions:

1. `x` is the word you want to remove. (`x == word`)
2. `x` is not the word you want to remove. (`otherwise`)

Comment: I thought for '(x:xs)' x would only match the first element in the list, so in ["Hi", "word"], x would return H, no?

Comment: @Phirip: `["Hi", "word"]` is a list of two elements. The first element is `"Hi"`. The second element is `"word"`. For `(x:xs)`, `x` would be `"Hi"`. You'd only get `H` if you used `((x:xs):ys)`.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much this is where it was giving me trouble. I thought it was only the first element and not the whole word. This clears up everything!

Comment: @Phirip: `"Hi"` is the first element of `["Hi", "word"]`. `'H'` is the first element of `"Hi"`. `'H'` would be the first element *of the first element* of `["Hi", "word"]`, and `:` only goes down one level.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a helper function, though you could write one if you wanted to.  You've basically got 3 conditions:

1. You get an empty list.
2. You get a list whose first element is the one you want to remove.
3. You get a list whose first element is anything else.

In other languages, you would do this with a set of if-else statements, or with a `case` statement, or a `cond`.  In Haskell, you can do this with guards:

```
remove_word_recursive:: String -> [String] -> [String]
remove_word_recursive _ []                              = []
remove_word_recursive test_word (x:xs) | test_word == x = what in this case?
remove_word_recursive test_word (x:xs)                  = what in default case?
```

Fill in the correct result for this function in these two conditions, and you should be done.

I think what you're looking for is a special case of the function sought for this question on string filters:  [Haskell - filter string list based on some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390173/haskell-filter-string-list-based-on-some-conditions?rq=1) . Reading some of the discussion on the accepted answer might help you understand more of Haskell.

Comment: Please don't spread the `underscore_naming_convention`, the `camelCaseConvention` seems to be the de-facto standard.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I wasn't aware of what was standard in the Haskell community, and `underscore_naming_convention` is the standard across languages where I am.  Is there discussion somewhere on why `camelCaseConvention` is superior for Haskell?

Comment: The [Haskell programming guidelines](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_guidelines) form some kind of authoritative source, and the `base` library (with `Prelude`) is written using that naming convention, along with most Haskell libraries on Hackage. The underscore is usually instead reserved for function versions that discard values (i.e. `mapM_` instead of `_ <- mapM`).

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to remove a list element, it's easy to do it with List Comprehension.

```
myList = ["hi", "today", "word", "Word", "WORD"]
[x | x <- myList, x /= "word"]
```

The result is:

```
["hi","today","Word","WORD"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If *isInfixOf* is not considered as higher order, then

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)
filter  (not . isInfixOf "word")  ["hi", "today", "word", "Word", "WORD"]
```